# array keyword before function parameters in PHP

Tags: php

I saw a function declared like this:

```
public static function factory($file=null, array $data=null, $auto_encode=null)
```

If you want to see the real class, please go to this `view.php` class from [a fork of fuelphp parser package](https://github.com/evantishuk/parser/blob/develop/classes/view.php) in github.

My question is, what does `array` keyword means in `array $data = null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [PHP5's type hinting](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.typehinting.php).  The parameter `$data` is supposed to be an array.  It is possible to hint method parameters as either `object` or `array` types.  If it is an object, you can specify the name of the class as the hint keyword.

Answer (score 3):

It requires the argument to be an array. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you can set a class name before a parameter to limit the variable type to that of the class, however, I'm not sure of `array`'s valid use here.

EDIT: Apparently my PHP is a bit rusty. According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php:

> PHP 5 introduces Type Hinting. Functions are now able to force parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the function prototype) or arrays (since PHP 5.1). However, if NULL is used as the default parameter value, it will be allowed as an argument for any later call.

For example:

```
// An example class
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * A test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an object of type OtherClass
     */
    public function test(OtherClass $otherclass) {
        echo $otherclass->var;
    }


    /**
     * Another test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an array
     */
    public function test_array(array $input_array) {
        print_r($input_array);
    }
}

// Another example class
class OtherClass {
    public $var = 'Hello World';
}
```

Comment: then you shouldv'e looked it up! =) Then you couldv'e provided an answer instead of "i dont know"

Comment: @Galen, looked it up. Linked reference and placed example.